# Unable to click with mouse

Tags: mouse

I have Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron n5010. Whenever I log in to Ubuntu my mouse works perfectly but when I open a window after that it stops working. I can still move it but am not able to click on any icon. The control is shifted to the recently opened window.

How can I fix this?